# IE8 doesn't respect table padding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This is a screenshot of a table in Chrome 5.

[image: Chrome]

The same table rendered in IE8:

[image: IE8]

You can view the page here:
http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/vspwpg/?page_id=96

This CSS rule adds the padding that IE8 won't respect:
`td#content table.subitems { padding: 5px; }`

Comment: that was my exact google search +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the padding to the td/th elements under the table, not the table itself. The table cells / headings get zeroed out by `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` as well, so you have to explicitly specify.

Edit: If you don't mean to put padding on *every* table cell/heading then try a margin on the table or padding on a table wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with my site. The class was applied to the `<td>` tag but its padding was not showing up. Then I declared the padding inline, and it showed up fine. I nearly put a fist through my monitor, but when I realized that would hurt me and not IE, I refrained. It's not pretty, but it works.

`<td class="doesntMatterBecauseIEHatesYou" style="padding:10px;">Horray, IE doesn't hate you anymore. But you still hate IE.</td>`